# Magento 2: Run a uninstall script when module is uninstalled via command line?

Tags: magento2, module, installation, install-script, uninstall

I am creating a module and I am progressing it. I am new to Magento 2 so there are a lot of things that I am not yet familiar too. As a module creator, I am curious how to run an uninstall script when someone uninstalled your module via command line.

I know I can execute the module uninstall command like this:

```
php bin/magento module:uninstall -r Vendor_Module
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Magento Setup Uninstall script

The below page in the Magento DevDocs explains the process of module uninstallation. It explains the steps that are taken and one of those steps is running Uninstall scripts of the modules:

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-uninstall-mods.html#instgde-cli-uninst-mod-uninst

> 6. If `--remove-data` is specified, removes the database schema and data defined in the module's `Uninstall` classes.
>
>    For each specified module to uninstall, invokes the `uninstall` method in its `Uninstall` class. This class must inherit from `Magento\Framework\Setup\UninstallInterface`.

So this indicates for a module to run a script at uninstall, the module should be uninstalled using the `--remove-data` option, or shorthand `-r`. So if the users of your module do not use that option, the script won't run.

For a *"Company MyModule"* module, the script should be located at `app/code/Company/MyModule/Setup/Uninstall.php` or `vendor/company/mymodule/Setup/Uninstall.php` and must implement the `\Magento\Framework\Setup\UninstallInterface` interface. It could look like this:

```
namespace Company\MyModule\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UninstallInterface;

class Uninstall implements UninstallInterface
{
    public function uninstall(
        SchemaSetupInterface $setup,
        ModuleContextInterface $context
    ) {
        $setup->startSetup();
        // Uninstall schema and/or data...
        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

---

#### Composer Package Uninstall event script

If your module is a composer package (residing in `vendor/`), then the Magento module uninstaller will run `composer remove` to remove the package files that were installed into the `vendor` dir.

Now, composer has a mechanism to run scripts on certain events, including package removal/uninstall. Unfortunately for module vendors, **only scripts configured in the root `composer.json`** will be ran. So if you have scripts configured like below in your root `composer.json` (root of your Magento project), then these will be triggered whenever a module will be uninstalled through the Magento `bin/magento module:uninstall` command:

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "pre-package-uninstall": "Company\\MyModule\\Setup\\Uninstall::composerUninstall",
        "post-package-uninstall": [
            "php -r \"copy('some-dir/some-file.php.backup', 'some-dir/some-file.php');\""
        ]
    }
}
```

https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md

Comment: This is what I needed! Thank you @7ochem!

Comment: It could be worth mentioning here that the Module being uninstalled should have been installed from composer. Manually Extracted modules wont work here.

Comment: It just work only when we install module via composer

Answer (score -1):

run : php bin/magento module:uninstall -r Vendor_Module

Comment: As how I read it, the question is not how to uninstall a module, but how to make a script run when the module is being uninstalled. @Ner Maybe you should clarify your question a little bit

Comment: @7ochem is right. I know how to execute the module uninstall command. What I wanted to know is how could I run a script when uninstall command is called.