# Magento 2: Is there any way for me to know that my extenstion has been removed by the shop owner

Tags: magento2

I have an extension deployed to some Magento stores. Is there any way for me to know when the shopowner uninstalls/ removes my extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I know of is to use the `Uninstall.php` file in your module's `Setup` directory to do whatever it is you want to do. This same question was answered here (with example): [Magento 2: Run a uninstall script when module is uninstalled via command line?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/208903/magento-2-run-a-uninstall-script-when-module-is-uninstalled-via-command-line)

One thing that isn't mentioned in the linked answer is that you're not *guaranteed* to have the user execute the uninstall command to remove your package. There are several ways to remove packages in Magento, and there isn't a way to guarantee your uninstallation code will be run.