# Magento 2 stuck in "Update pending" when trying to uninstall a Magento Extension

Tags: magento2, extensions, uninstall-module

I'm currently trying to uninstall an extension that I installed using "Magento Marketplace" on a Magento 2.2.7 install but every time I try it gets stuck in the "Update pending" stage.

There are no errors in the developer console or in the console log.

[image]

Is there a solution for this or any other way to uninstall the extension?

Comment: check this one mate https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/208903/magento-2-run-a-uninstall-script-when-module-is-uninstalled-via-command-line?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: i have recently this type problem and you have  rollback it and manually extension install

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can uninstall module using `php bin/magento module:uninstall Namespace_Modulename`. [(For more information click here)](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-uninstall-mods.html)

> This command works only with modules defined as Composer packages.

If you did not install the module via composer, it won't work.

You can only disable it via `php bin/magento module:disable Namespace_Modulename`

To remove module run below command.

`cd app/code/<ExtensionProvider>/`

`rm -rf <ExtensionName>`

I hope it helps!